# Apply custom function to 2 dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I got these 2 dataframes

```
data = {
    'col1': {1: 9, 2: 20, 3: 35, 4: 47, 5: 30, 6: 8},
    'col2': {1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 30, 4: 45, 5: 46, 6: 85},
    'col3': {1: 11, 2: 18, 3: 22, 4: 27, 5: 32, 6: 90},
}

thresholds = {
    0: {1: 0, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 0, 5: 40, 6: 0},
    1: {1: 10, 2: 15, 3: 25, 4: 10, 5: 50, 6: 1},
    2: {1: 20, 2: 17, 3: 29, 4: 60, 5: 60, 6: 2},
    3: {1: 30, 2: 25, 3: 39, 4: 70, 5: 70, 6: 3},
    4: {1: 40, 2: 35, 3: 50, 4: 75, 5: 80, 6: 10},
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
thresholds = pd.DataFrame(thresholds)
```

where the amount of `rows` is the same for both dataframes.

I need to obtain another dataframe that introduces one column of `data` (for example 'col1') in `thresholds`, and it fits every element of the column in its corresponding position in the row, returning all the indexes.

Here are the dataframes when printed.

`data`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     9     1    11
2    20     5    18
3    35    30    22
4    47    45    27
5    30    46    32
6     8    85    90
```

`thresholds`:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
1   0  10  20  30  40
2  10  15  17  25  35
3  20  25  29  39  50
4   0  10  60  70  75
5  40  50  60  70  80
6   0   1   2   3  10
```

`result`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
1     1     1     2
2     3     0     3
3     3     3     1
4     2     2     2
5     0     1     0
6     4     5     5
```

Examples: `result['col1'][1]` is `1` because `data['col1'][1] --> 9` would be in position `1` when introduced in row `1` of `thresholds`: `[0, 10,  20,  30,  40]`

`result['col2'][6]` is `5` because `data['col2'][6] --> 85` would be in position `5` when introduced in row `6` of `thresholds`: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 10]`

I am looking for the `result` dataframe using `pandas`. I found a function in pandas named `searchsorted`, and I know that I need to use `.apply()` (or `.applymap()`), and use `lambda` somewhere. I just don't know how to put the pieces together.

`for` loops are no good, too slow. The real dataframes are large, with thousands of rows and columns.

Here is the `result` dataframe in code (in case needed):

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 4},
        'col2': {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 5},
        'col3': {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 5},
    }
)
```

Comment: row 6 of thresholds is not `[40, 50, 60, 70, 80]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case apply the `searchsorted` from `numpy`

```
result = data.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(np.searchsorted(thresholds.loc[x.name],x)),axis=1)
Out[13]: 
   0  1  2
1  1  1  2
2  3  0  3
3  3  3  1
4  2  2  2
5  0  1  0
6  4  5  5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way do to it where 'result' has the column names as in 'data' dataframe ('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), without introducing it afterwards?

Comment: @ArmanMojaver result = data.copy() ; result [:] = data.apply(lambda x : np.searchsorted(thresholds.loc[x.name],x),axis=1).tolist()